# One Night ultimate werewolf Hunter Question

Tags: one-night-werewolf

So I just bought One Night ultimate werewolf and I am about to play it for the first time in about 2 hours but I have a few questions:

1. I know that in the night, you do the action of whatever was your card at the start of the game, regardless of if that card was switched. But what about the Hunter? So if I start with the hunter, but later on it gets switched and I don't know that. At the end of the game I die, can I still point at someone that also dies? Or do I actually need to have the hunter card.
2. Likewise if someone dies and figures out they have the hunter card, are they allowed to use the hunter power?
3. If a doppelganger copies the hunter power, how does she prove that the hunter was the card that she looked at? I don't think my friend group would cheat but I also don't like having the option for someone to lie outside of the game content (lieing inside the game is of course great).

Let me know if that didn't make sense. I have searched for these answers but can't seem to find them so it must be something simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: The whole idea of *who you are* in ONUW isn't as clearly presented as it should be, so you are perfectly within reason to be confused!

Answer (score 3):

1. For voting, it matters who has the hunter when voting, not who started with it. What you started with only matters for what you do during the night phase. Similar with the Tanner and the Werewolves.
2. For the doppelgänger, you just have to trust them. You always have to trust them to tell the truth about what they copied, no matter what it is.

Answer (score 0):

1) & 2)

> If Hunter dies, the player he is pointing at dies as well

So it resolves like this: you are voted out > you reveal your card and find out you're a Hunter > the person you pointed at during voting also dies. It doesn't matter who was Hunter originally, just who is Hunter at the end.

3) If it bothers you that much, have Doppelganger write role they saw and possibly person who had it during their night phase.